# how to render div on all free space in browser

Tags: html, css

Just for experiment I tried simple html ccs snnipet.

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u768afb3/

But it don't fill space. What need I do?

**CSS**

```
html body
{
     heigth:100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

div.layout{
    border: 1px greay solid;
    heigth:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="layout"></div>
```

Comment: Change "greay" ---> "grey". You have a typo error.

Answer (score 3):

1. It's `CSS`, not `CCS`;
2. Selector for HTML and BODY must be `html, body` not `html body`;
3. It's `height`, not `heigth`;
4. It's `2px gray solid;`, not `2px greay solid;`;

After that everything works:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.layout {
  border: 2px grey solid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">

</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry for misprints.